# Retrieve php data returning unusal data

Tags: php, mysql

All i am trying to do is return count number of rows from the database.

This is the code:

```
<?
   echo "sdsdsdsdsd";

?>
```

The result i am getting is:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf360 {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;} {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;} \paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww9000\viewh8400\viewkind0 \pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\ql\qnatural\pardirnatural \f0\fs24 \cf0 sdsdsdsdsd\ }

Why is this data showing?
Why isnt the echo just displaying the string value?

Comment: This makes zero sense. What are you doing in what context? (For what it's worth, the result you show seems to be the source code of a RTF file)

Comment: i saved the document as rtf then changed the file extension to php

Comment: @redoc01: that's like "compiling" your program by doing `ren helloworld.c hellword.exe`. It's possible to embed php in an rtf file, but not by SAVING it as an rtf.

Comment: the thing is i am using apple mac and it the text editor doesnt allow me to save to php, i have to save rtf then change the file extension to .php

Comment: @redoc01 Instead of using text editor (which will save the rtf with all of the extra rtf data and not as plain text), try using jEdit (http://www.jedit.org/). I develop on Mac and that's what I use. jEdit will let you save as .php in plain text.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use WordPad to write PHP code (a strange choice) you need to save the file as *plain text*, not rich text.

**Update:** Even if it's not WordPad, you need a text editor that's able to produce plain text. If your editor cannot do that, you need to find another one.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wordpad (`rtf` editor) to edit? use editors like `Notepad++`.

**[Update]:**

Editors like `wordpad` (as in your case the editor `TextEdit` - `Mac OsX`) comes by default as `RTF` (Rich Text Format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)

should use plain text to use it:

**`Code Editor` for Mac OS X:**

- http://tacosw.com/htmledit/screenshots.php
- http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/ (**Note:** Cross-platform)

---

**`Code Editor` for Linux (like Linux):**

- gpedit (install `apt-get install gedit`) **Note:** default in gnome
- leafpad (install `apt-get install leafpad`) **Note:** default in lxde

---

**`Code Editor` for Android:**

- http://www.touchqode.com/ (touchqode)

---

**`Code Editor` and `FTP client` for iOS (Iphone and Ipad):**

- https://itunes.apple.com/hr/app/codeanywhere/id436736239?mt=8 (Codeanywhere)

---

**`Code Editor` and `FTP client` for `Google Chorme`:**

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/codeanywhere/ndcfkjjcjfpmmhdedhnbkknbehiadgjg

---

**`Code Editor` for Java (VM):**

- http://www.jedit.org/ (jedit)

---

**`Code Editor` for Windows:**

- http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.2.2.html (notepad++)
- http://www.editpadlite.com/ (editpad lite)
- http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html (notepad2)

Comment: Nice list.  Problem is, you don't even bother to explain why it's relevant.

Comment: I accidentally deleted that part. Thanks.